# Performance problems with the C++20 spaceship operator?

Tags: c++, performance, comparison, c++20, spaceship-operator

Since C++20 the standard library uses the *spaceship operator* to implement comparison for strings and vectors (according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRkJCvHWdwQ)). I am worried that this comes with a potentially huge performance penalty!

Let me explain on the example of the operator `!=` for `string`:

- When I write `str1 != str2`, the compiler now translates this to `(str1 <=> str2) != 0`.
- However, an efficient implementation of `!=` for `string` would have first checked for `str1.size() != str2.size()`, and only on failure moved to comparing the actual characters.
- This optimization cannot be implemented for the spaceship operator, as it has to determine the "larger" string anyway.

So if this is truely how strings are compared for inequality now, isn't this a huge performance loss?

Comment: _Does_ the compiler automatically translate it to the spaceship operator for `!=`? According to [this](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2019/07/28/comparisons-cpp20/), at least, `operator==` is still a primary comparison method. While the compiler may still synthesize a comparison even if you haven't defined `operator!=`, it won't use the spaceship operator. So you can write fast `operator==` and get fast `!=`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That was already addressed by the standardization committee in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r2.html. That change says that `a == b` and `a != b` are not calling `operator <=>`, they are calling `operator==` and `operator !=`. The behavior that you describe was a temporary version of the C++20 standard that was later revised.

The linked change request exactly gives `std::vector` as an example where `==` can compare more efficiently than `<=>`.